# Converting Timestamp to different format

Tags: timestamp, google-bigquery

I have a big CSV file and contains wrong timestamp format (8/1/2014 0:03:00) and want to import into BigQuery. How can I convert it to different format (2014-08-19 07:41:35.220) ??

ERROR during the process

```
File: 0 / Line:1 / Field:1, Could not parse '8/1/2014 0:03:00' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) to convert to a timestamp, or use a [regexp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions) to convert it to BigQuery's expected string format before casting to a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using your reference timestamp.  I ran into similar problems, and came up with something like this.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(year,"-",month,"-",day," ",clock) as bq_formatted_date,
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        IF(LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_orig, r'([^\/]+)\/')) = 1, CONCAT("0",REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_orig, r'([^\/]+)\/')), REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_orig, r'([^\/]+)\/')) as month,
        IF(LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_orig, r'.*?\/([^\/]+)\/')) = 1, CONCAT("0",REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_orig, r'.*?\/([^\/]+)\/')),REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_orig, r'.*?\/([^\/]+)\/')) as day,
        REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_orig, r'.*\/([0-9]+)') as year,
        REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_orig, r'([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)') as clock
    FROM (SELECT "8/1/2014 0:03:00" as date_orig)
    )
```

Which gives you this as output `2014-08-01 0:03:00`.  This regular expression will pad single digit months or days with a leading zero.

Comment: but I have to specify a schema before import, how can I run a query before importing the table?

Comment: Import as a string and then use this query to convert it afterward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PARSE_DATETIME`

```
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",'8/1/2014 0:03:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since this is a CSV file, you could use our Federated Data Sources (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources) to query the CSV file directly and do the conversion as you import the data. Query would still be the same as Steve suggests.